# Javascript increment result of input and include comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I can't seem to get this working and it's driving me insane. I've made a JSFiddle and am keen for anyone with more knowledge than me to take a look! http://jsfiddle.net/kLQf3/9/

Basically what I am trying to do is get the user to be able to put a figure (comma included) in the first "To" field ie. "60,000" and I want this number to display in the "From" field it incremented by 1 ie. "60,001".

And the same for the input box. I have limited knowledge of JS but I've got the auto update working but the increment keeps giving me NaN errors because the comma is included.

```
window.onload = function () {
  var first = document.getElementById('firstFieldId'),
      second = document.getElementById('secondFieldId'),
      third = document.getElementById('thirdFieldId'),
      fourth = document.getElementById('fourthFieldId');

  first.onchange = function () {
    second.value = first.value;
  third.onchange = function () {
    fourth.value = third.value;
};
};
};
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, I've removed the tag.

Comment: You've tagged your question `jquery`, but aren't using jQuery in the code you've quoted. Are you using jQuery in your project?

Comment: Yes, jQuery in the project and the whole project is PHP but I guess that's not relevant to the question. Thanks

Comment: @ verruck: I'd take an hour to read through the jQuery API and do a tutorial or two. Most of your question doesn't relate to jQuery, but it applies to the code you quoted surrounding the question about commas and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you get the value you want into the variable `value`...

...to remove the comma:

```
value = value.replace(/,/g, "");
```

...to parse the number:

```
value = parseInt(value, 10); // 10 = base 10
```

Adding back a comma is trickier, but SO already has that covered: [*How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript).

Example applied to your `first.onchange` handler: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLQf3/16/)

```
first.onchange = function () {
    var value;

    // Get the value and remove the commas
    value = first.value.replace(/,/g, "");

    // Make it a number
    value = parseInt(value, 10);

    // Add one to it
    ++value;

    // Turn it back into a string
    value = String(value);

    // Put it in the other text box, formatted with commas
    second.value = numberWithCommas(value);
};
```

You can do that all at once, but it makes debugging more difficult:

```
first.onchange = function () {
    second.value = numberWithCommas(String(parseInt(first.value.replace(/,/g, ""), 10) + 1));
};
```

---

You have some other issues with that code, not least that you don't hook up your change handler on `third` until the first time `first` is changed. If you format your code consistently, that becomes more apparent:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var first = document.getElementById('firstFieldId'),
        second = document.getElementById('secondFieldId'),
        third = document.getElementById('thirdFieldId'),
        fourth = document.getElementById('fourthFieldId');

    first.onchange = function () {
        second.value = first.value;
        third.onchange = function () {
            fourth.value = third.value;
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder! Are you able to include it in the JSFiddle so I can see where `parseInt` goes? I've never used that before. :/

Comment: @verrucktfuchs: To add one to the number, you need it to be a number, not a string. So use `parseInt` to turn the string you get from the input element into a number before you add 1 to it.

Comment: Ok still a tad lost but I'll give it a go. Still pretty new to this stuff! Thanks again. :)

Comment: @verrucktfuchs: I've given you an example for `first.onchange` and made another note above.

Answer (score 1):

Just using parseint or pasefloat:

```
window.onload = function () {
var first = document.getElementById('firstFieldId'),
  second = document.getElementById('secondFieldId'),
  third = document.getElementById('thirdFieldId'),
  fourth = document.getElementById('fourthFieldId');

first.onchange = function () {
second.value =  parseFloat(first.value)+1;
alert(second.value);
third.onchange = function () {
fourth.value = parseFloat(third.value)+1;
};
};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function () {
  var first = document.getElementById('firstFieldId'),
      second = document.getElementById('secondFieldId'),
      third = document.getElementById('thirdFieldId'),
      fourth = document.getElementById('fourthFieldId');

  first.onchange = function () {
    second.value = parseInt(first.value.replace(/,/g, "")) +1;
  third.onchange = function () {
    fourth.value = parseInt(third.value.replace(/,/g, "")) +1;
};
};
};
```

pretty much what T.J. Crowder said, but here is your fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/kLQf3/17/